# UILabel doesn't show text properly in Emulator and real device as it does in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have some static Label with static text that will not change forever.

I adjust the layout in Interface Builder until they look great. and use Cmd + = to let all label's size fit their contents.

But when I run and test them on emulator and device they become truncate even though they look fit in the Interface Builder.

I have test it on iOS 5.0, 6.1 and on 3.5, 4 inches include on iphone5 device. All the result are different from in Interface Builder.

Emulator
[image]

Interface Builder
[image]

Any help to overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this code for fitting the label content.

For that you need to have a IBOutlet for the label and then after that,

use this code when you load the view :

`[self.label sizeToFit];`

Hope that works !

Comment: your solution solve my problem!. but I don't understand why the labels' size are not fit as in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

As there's a change in DateFormatter it's creating a problem. In your XIB, date is in different format than your device.

You can set Minimum Font Size for your label from your XIB. Check below screenshot.

[image: Minimum Font Size]

I hope it'll solve your problem.

Thanks,

Hemang.

Comment: Yes, the dateformatter change the whole thing and because May is longer than Jul. Thank you very much.