# UILabel doesn't show text properly

Tags: ios, interface, uilabel

I have `UILabel` in interface builder like this (creating text and use Cmd + =)

[image]

but when i run the program on emulator or real device, it looks like this

[image]

the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828737/uilabel-doesnt-show-text-properly-in-emulator-and-real-device-as-it-does-in-int) can solve my issue but it isn't the best way because i don't want to create all my label as an IBOutlet for calling `sizeToFit` and i also don't want to scale down my text.

is there any way to display text in the device as it shows in interface builder without additional code or configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just make the label larger or the text smaller?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just strictly not wanting to do any of it in code, simply press Editor -> Size to Fit Content when you have the label selected in IB.

Comment: i have already done that. It shows perfectly in interface builder as in the picture but not on the emulator and the device.

Comment: I'm guessing there's an auto-resize hanging around somewhere, doing it's dastardly deeds.

Answer (score 1):

Select your label in the interface builder, and then in the utility area found on the right hand side, go to the "Size Inspector", look for this icon --> [image: Size Inspector]
 
In there you will see options to set your label's origin, width and height

Increase the "width" of your label and that should fix your problem